# Flutter - How to create a TabBar View with top bottom as the same levels as the tab

Tags: flutter

I have a TabBar that has form items in the view. that currently look like this.

[image]

as you can see the Cancel and Continue buttons are at the top. I used a Scalfold widget with an AppBar for those.

The problem is I want the continued bottom to align with the tabs. like this.

[image]

How can I get that desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                YourFirstButton,
                YourTabBar(),
                YourSecondButton(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```